# Error: Cannot find module 'firebase' when running JS file with node command

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have started the following before running my JS file:

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

After that I tried to run my Firebase function using the following command, which was working several months ago:

```
node sendEmail.js
```

But I get the following errors:

```
D:\Firebase\imtp\testing>node sendEmail.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'firebase'
Require stack:
- D:\Firebase\imtp\testing\sendEmail.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)       
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Firebase\imtp\testing\sendEmail.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\Firebase\\imtp\\testing\\sendEmail.js' ]
}
```

I have tried the following but no luck:

1. Remove the `node_modules` folder of my `functions` folder and run `npm i --save firebase-functions`.
2. Remove the root `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.

FYI, in my `sendEmail.js`, I do have the following code:

**(NOTE: This is just a caller to my function.)**

```
"use strict";
// Initialize Function Caller App
const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/functions");

var config = {
  // My config info here.
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var functions = firebase.functions();
// Prepare data
const contactInfo = {
  firstName : "John",
  lastName : "Rambo",
  email : "rambo@gmail.com",
  subject : "Test Nodemailer v2.0",
  message : "Hi from sendEmail.js!"
};

// Call Firebase Function
var sendEmail = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sendEmail');
sendEmail(contactInfo).then(function (result) {
  const status = result.data.status;

  if (status == true) {
    console.log("Email successfully sent!");
  } else {
    console.log("Failed to send email: " + JSON.stringify(result.data));
  }

}).catch(function (error) {
  // Getting the Error details.
  var code = error.code;
  var message = error.message;
  var details = error.details;

  console.log(details);
});
```

May I know what else should I do or check in order to fix this error? Let me know if you need greater detail of my `sendEmail.js`. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your **entire** Cloud Functions code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the firebase module:

```
npm i firebase
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

Comment: u installed `npm i --save firebase-functions` according to the question.. in the `package.json` do you see the `firebase` module there?

Comment: Yes, under `dependencies`, `"firebase": "^5.10.0"`. In fact, I also run `npm install -g firebase-tools` again, but still the same. Do I need to install it under the `testing` folder as well? I thought my Firebase should be **global**?